Video will behave differently across devices
I'm using the <video> tag in a HTML code for a website.
The video will work without any issues on PC, but as soon as I load the site on my phone it will load but wont play, and on another phone in the exact same browser (safari) it wont play unless clicked on and it opens a window (pop out) for it.
This is the code for the HTML that I tried so far...
   <div class="video_container">
      <video
        autoplay
        muted
        loop
        src="./resources/videos/excursion.mp4"
        type="video/mp4"
      >
        Video not compatible with your browser
      </video>

If you require any additional information please let me know.

Browser's auto-play policy has gotten really strict and fairly complicated over the years, as auto-playing videos have been abused a lot. It simply might not auto-play.

I read about this in the MWD  tag, also read the autoplay guide, which only states that it most likely wont autoplay if it has sound enabled which is why I muted it. It also stated that it may be browser allowed, but it shouldn't be whats causing the problem for me since the browser I'm testing on is the same, is just a device change both are iPhones too. For the time being the marked answer worked for me on one of them, I will have to check on the other one when I have the chance.

try playsinline in video tag
<video
        autoplay
        muted
        loop
        playsinline
        src="./resources/videos/excursion.mp4"
        type="video/mp4"
      >


Try having both video formats and give it a height and a width.


<video width="220" height="140" controls>
  <source src="./resources/videos/excursion.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="./resources/videos/excursion.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>



Happy Coding!

Would I have to convert the file to ogg? Or is this an automatic process done by the browser?

convert it and upload it to your assets folder. try convertio.io
